# nuxt router.js automatically updates how to prevent this?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I have a `nuxt` project. And located in the `.nuxt` file there is a router.js file when i want to add my own code to it like this:

```
routes: [{
    path: "/ingelogd",
    component: _0716b7e1,
    name: "ingelogd",
    meta: {requiresAuth: true}
  }]

router.beforeEach((to, from, next)=> {
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);
  const isAuthenticated = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  if(requiresAuth && !isAuthenticated) {
    next("/reserveren")
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

it automatically updates the code to this:

```
routes: [{
    path: "/ingelogd",
    component: _0716b7e1,
    name: "ingelogd",
  }]
```

Is there someone who knows what the problem is please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't edit any file in your `.nuxt` directory, here is the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/nuxt) about it.

You should use router middlewares to execute this kind of logic, [take a look!](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/middleware#router-middleware)

Comment: Thank you @Giovane i didn't know.

Answer (score 1):

You should not modify any file in the `.nuxt` directory. In this situation you should work with [middleware](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/middleware),
in `middleware` folder in the project root add file named `auth.js` with a content like :

```
export default function ({ app,route }) {
 
app.router.beforeEach((to, from, next)=> {
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);
  const isAuthenticated = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  if(requiresAuth && !isAuthenticated) {
    next("/reserveren")
  } else {
    next()
  }
})

}
```

Then, in your `nuxt.config.js` add :

```
  router: {
    middleware: 'auth'
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @BoussadjraBrahim i didn't know that i should never do that and this worked for me thank you!